# JOIN function in python is adding a letter to the end of string

Tags: string, function, join

```
str2=""

letters="abc"

for letter in letters:

    print(str2)

    str2=str2.join(letter)

    print(str2)
```

This is printing
' '

a

a

b

b

c

When i want it to print, works fine when i use + instead of join()
' '

a

a

ab

ab

abc

Comment: `str2 += letter` instead of `str2=str2.join(letter)` ?

Comment: + works fine, but shouldn't join() also work @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Because `letter` only has one char. So `"anything".join(single_letter)` will result in `single_letter`.

Answer (score 0):

`str.join()` does a different thing than what you think, @Johnny Mopp comment on the question explains very well why it's not working as you intend. Here's the documentation for str.join():
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join

Here’s the correct code for the output that you want:

```
str2=""

letters="abc"

for letter in letters:

    print(str2)

    str2 = str2 + letter

    print(str2)
```